# How does a landlord establish that a tenant is liable for damages?

Tags: tenant, damages

Suppose landlords are blaming a tenant for a pipe leak hidden behind dry wall that the tenant did not cause and are using it as justification for claiming the whole of a tenant's security deposit plus thousands of dollars in additional damages. How can the tenant be held liable for this damage given that the tenant claims that they did not recognize the problem since visible observations of the problem only manifested themselves gradually over time and did not affect their habitation of the dwelling?

How would a landlord establish that the damages directly resulted from conduct not reasonably expected in the course of habitation of a dwelling on the part of the tenant? What legal means does a tenant have for defending against such a situation?

Comment: Tenant laws vary; what city/state are you in?

Comment: The short answer is "in a court". Given the amount of money involved you should probably talk to a lawyer sooner rather than later.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Michigan